# react-redux : TypeError: store.getState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

Recently I'm learning react and redux, when I tried to display different modules based on whether there is a userID, error occurs:
  [image: error]

here's how I initialized the store:

```
import React,{Children} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

import {BrowserRouter,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
    import RootReducer from './reducers/index'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store = createStore(RootReducer);


    ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={{store}}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>  ,
    document.getElementById('root')); 
    registerServiceWorker();
```

and here's the place I used connect() to generate a container:

```
 import React from 'react'
  import {Dropdown,Button,Menu} from 'antd'  
  import {connect} from 'react-redux'
  import  {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import logo from '../../logo.svg'
const menu = (
    <Menu>
        <Menu.Item>
            <Link to='/home/accountInfo'>Account Information</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        ... //just some links, I think they are correct
    </Menu>
);
const mapStateToProps= state=>{
    return{
        userID: state.userID
    } 
}
const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch=>{
    return{}
}

  const topBarIcon=function({userID=undefined}) {
      if(userID)
      return (
          <div>
              <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
                  <Link to='/home/accountInfo'>
                      <Button shape="circle" gost>
                          {JSON.stringify(userID)}
                          <img src={logo} alt='UserLogo' height="30" width="30"/>
                      </Button>
                      </Link>

              </Dropdown>
          </div>
          );
      return(
          <div>
              <Link to='/login'>
                  <Button type="primary" className="LoginButton">
                      Login
                  </Button>
              </Link>
          </div>
      );
  } 
const TopBarIcon= connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps())(topBarIcon)
export default  TopBarIcon
```

The way I use the store should be quite similar to the sample in the react-redux document, and I'm not sure which step is the cause of such error. I tried declaring the dispatch in the props instead of the connect() parameter, but the error still exists.

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `<Provider store={store}>`

You have added an extra parenthesis

Comment: You are right...sorry for the silly mistake, but if I don't call connect() such error won't occur... It's quite strange.

Comment: @XU Lu The `<Provider>` component expects a store as a prop. What you provided with `store={{store}}`is an object that has a property `store` instead of being the store itself. And that object, which you create inline, has no property `getState()`. That's why you see this error. Giovanni Giordano is right.